# Why do we need & at some place and not in the other place when calling functions when both are taking pointer type arguments?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, queue, function-pointers

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define QUEUESIZE 30

    int qfull(int *r)
    {
        if(*r == QUEUESIZE-1)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }


    int qempty(int *f,int *r)
    {
        if(*f > *r)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    void enqueue(int item,int q[], int *r)
    {
        if(qfull(r))
        {
            printf("Cannot Insert. Queue full.\n");
            return;
        }

        (*r)++;
        q[*r] = item;
    }

    void dequeue(int q[], int *r, int *f)
    {
        if(qempty(f,r))
        {
            printf("The queue is empty\n");
            return;
        }

        int item_deleted = q[*f];
        (*f)++;

        if(*f > *r)
        {
            *f = 0;
            *r = -1;
        }
    }

    void display(int q[], int *f, int *r)
    {
        if(qempty(f,r))
        {
            printf("Nothing to display.\n");
            return;
        }

        for(int i=*f; i<=(*r); i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n",q[i]);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int f = 0;
        int r = -1;

        int q[QUEUESIZE];

        int item,choice;

        while(1)
        {
            printf("Enter a choice: \n");
            printf("1. Enqueue\n");
            printf("2. Dequeue\n");
            printf("3. Display\n");
            printf("4. Exit\n");

            scanf("%d",&choice);

            switch(choice)
            {
                    case 1:
                    printf("Enter an item: \n");
                    scanf("%d",&item);
                    enqueue(item,q,&r);
                    break;

                    case 2:
                    dequeue(q,&r,&f);
                    break;

                    case 3:
                    display(q,&f,&r);
                    break;

                    default: exit(0);
            }
        }   
    }
```

This is my code.
When I am calling the enqueue function in the main program and I take r instead of &r, it gives me a [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSYQS.png).

When I take &r while calling qfull() function in the definition of enqueue it gives me this [warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcT5l.png).

I want to know why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I am calling the enqueue function in the main program
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>     ...
>     int r = -1;
>       ...
>       enqueue(item,q,&r)
> ```

and

> calling qfull() function in the definition of enqueue
>
> ```
> void enqueue(int item,int q[], int *r)
> {
>     if(qfull(r))
> ```

`int r` and `int * r` do not define the same `r`.

The former is an `int` the latter is a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: Could you answer more appropriately?

Comment: Both the arguments contain pointer to the int. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: @AshwaniJha: In the 1st case you pass an 
`r`, which is an `int`, in the second you pass `r` being an `int*`. Plaase see my updated answer.